# Pass parameter to django as_view function

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have one url that passes a parameter through the `as_view` function:

```
url(
    r'^$',
    ChangeListView.as_view(
        columns=('username', 'email')
    ),
    name="user-list"
),
```

When i try to access the columns attribute in the view it returns None instead of the tuple that i have passed through the url

```
class ChangeListView(generic.ListView):
    columns = None

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print(self.columns)
        # Returns None instead of tuple
        return context
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have anything that actually sets `self.columns` from the data you pass in.

But this isn't the right way to do it. Instead, pass it as an [extra option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#views-extra-options), and access it from the kwargs.

```
url(
    r'^$',
    ChangeListView.as_view(),
    {'columns': ('username', 'email')}
    name="user-list"
),
```

...

```
print(self.kwargs['columns'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now i get a key error when i try to access self.kwargs['columns']

Comment: please do change `kwargs = {'columns': ('username', 'email')}` in `url()`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that; this code works fine for me as is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your question - any arguments passed to `as_view` should have been set as attributes on the view instance, so `self.columns` should be set to `('username', 'email')`.

(See the source for [Django's base View class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L49%20Django's%20base%20View%20class))

However, the `context` variable (which is what you're returning) *should* be `None` in this case - what you pass to `as_view()` does not affect what is returned from `self.get_context_data()` (which is `None` by default). Maybe you meant to write `return self.columns`?

On the other hand, if you meant that `print(self.columns)` unexpectedly prints nothing then I'm not sure what's going on.